# How to reset a Completer to a future

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter's official WebView.

```
Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();  //State class variable

return WebView(
                    key: widget.key,
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    initialUrl: "$baseUrl/course.html",
                    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                      _controller.complete(webViewController); // here is the problem
                    },
                    onPageFinished: (url) {
                      _showPageTitle();
                    },
                    javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[createChannel()].toSet(),
                  );
```

Works fine when I initially go to the screen, but when I do a back press and forward press  I get

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:43:31)
```

So my `_controller` is already complete. It's as if the screen is holding the state of the `_controller`.

I'm tried using  a UniqueKey with the `WebView`  but that hasn't worked. Is there something I can do in `dispose` or `willPopScope` How to I get the completer to "uncomplete" for want of a better phrase!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reassign it everytime?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller = new Completer<WebViewController>();
    return WebView(
        ...
```

Comment: Think so, but I'll try again

Comment: no joy. Tried to reassign in initState and the build method. Seem I have to "tear it down"

Comment: maybe it is because it has the widget.key, so it maintain alive the _controller.
However if you reasign a new Completer right before the "return WebView(" it gues it should reset.